# Show that $\Vert x-y\Vert\ge\tfrac12\max(\Vert x\Vert,\,\Vert y\Vert)\left\Vert\tfrac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}-\tfrac{y}{\Vert y\Vert}\right\Vert$

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Given that $x,\,y$ belong to a normed vector space with $0\ne x\ne y\ne0$.
i've tried taking $\Vert x \Vert$ as the max and tried to factor by the norm of x but it lead me to nowhere. i also tried using the inverse triangular inequality.

Comment: Voted to close because you showed no effort of your own on the problem. (You can click "edit" just below the question to show us what you've tried and where you're stuck, and I'll remove my vote to close.)

Comment: Hint. Draw  the plane containing the vectors, and some circles there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG we may assume $\|x\|\ge\|y\|$. So we need to prove

$$\left\lVert x-\frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} y\right\rVert\le2\lVert x-y\rVert.$$

Using the triangle inequality, we get

$$\left\lVert x-\frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} y\right\rVert=\left\lVert (x-y)+\left(y-\frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} y\right)\right\rVert\le\lVert x-y\rVert+\left(\frac{\lVert x\rVert}{\lVert y\rVert}-1\right)\lVert y\rVert.$$

The right-hand side equals

$$\lVert x-y\rVert+\lVert x\rVert - \lVert y\rVert.$$

Using the triangle inequality again yields

$$\lVert x \rVert - \lVert y\rVert = \lVert (x-y)+y\rVert - \lVert y\rVert \le\lVert x-y\rVert+0,$$

which proves our initial assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality assume $\|x\|=\max\{\|x\|,\|y\|\}$. Then your problem is equivalent to shown whether the following holds:

$$
 \Big\| \frac{x}{\|x\|}-\frac{y}{\|x\|}\Big\|\ge\frac12\left\Vert\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}-\frac{y}{\Vert y\Vert}\right\|
$$

Let $u_x=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and $u_y=\frac{y}{\|y\|}$

Then by the triangle inequality

\begin{align}
\Big\|u_x-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}u_y\Big\|&\geq \|u_x-u_y\|-\Big(1-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}\Big)\\
&\geq \|u_x-u_y\| - \Big\|u_x-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}u_y\Big\|
\end{align}

since $1-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}\leq \Big\|u_x-\frac{\|y\|}{\|x\|}u_y\Big\|$